# JS: simple hitArea code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recall from Actionscript that was very easy to detect when two elements were touching, very useful for games for instance, just a method called `hitArea`

since I'm in rush and i cant write the code from scratch I wonder if there is anything easy to use, a plugin maybe that works in JS and can tell me when elemA and elemB are in the same spot on the screen

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

actually  JQuery Collision is the answer